# Quickest way to dump Python dictionary (dict) object to a MySQL table?

Tags: python, mysql, dictionary

I have a dict object. I dumped the data using this:

```
for alldata in data: # print all data to screen
    print data[alldata]
```

Each field had brackets [] and 'None' values for NULLS and date.datetime for date values.

How do I dump this dict to MySQL table? Thank you!

print data displays something like this :

```
{'1': ['1', 'K', abc, 'xyz', None, None, None], '2': ['2', 'K', efg, 'xyz', None, None, None], '3': ['3', 'K', ijk, 'xyz', None, None, None]}
```

How to insert this data into MySQL?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming you have [MySQLdb](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python) (mysql-python) installed:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO mytable (a,b,c) VALUES (%(qwe)s, %(asd)s, %(zxc)s);"
data = {'qwe':1, 'asd':2, 'zxc':None}

conn = MySQLdb.connect(**params)

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql, data)
cursor.close()

conn.close()
```

Comment: print data displays something like this :

{'1': ['1', 'K', abc, 'xyz', None, None, None], '2': ['2', 'K', efg, 'xyz', None, None, None], '3': ['3', 'K', ijk, 'xyz', None, None, None]}

How to insert this data into MySQL?

Comment: sql = "INSERT INTO mytable (a,b,c,d,e,f,g) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s);"
...
cursor.executemany(sql, list(data))
...

Answer (score 4):

this one is giving a very nice example and more compatible one. 
http://code.activestate.com/recipes/457661-generate-sql-for-insertation-into-table-from-dicti/

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible duplicate of, or can be answered by this post
[Using a Python dict for a SQL INSERT statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9336270/using-a-python-dict-for-a-sql-insert-statement/44530019#44530019)

However, to answer your question, I posted this over on the other question and i'm reposting it here as well:

```
def ins_query_maker(tablename, rowdict):
keys = tuple(rowdict)
dictsize = len(rowdict)
sql = ''
for i in range(dictsize) :
    if(type(rowdict[keys[i]]).__name__ == 'str'):
        sql += '\'' + str(rowdict[keys[i]]) + '\''
    else:
        sql += str(rowdict[keys[i]])
    if(i< dictsize-1):
        sql += ', '
query = "insert into " + str(tablename) + " " + str(keys) + " values (" + sql + ")"
print(query) # for demo purposes we do this
return(query) #in real code we do this
```

For a dictionary

```
tab = {'idnumber': 1, 'fname': 'some', 'lname': 'dude', 'dob': '15/08/1947', 'mobile': 5550000914, 'age' : 70.4}
```

we get the output as the screenshot below shows. Note this is a bare-bones example and needs sanity checks, and can be modified for bulk updates (using a dict of dicts), etc.

[image: output of the code mentioned above]

Comment: The above is bad practice because it invites sql injection attacks. Always use library supplied functions for sql composition or query parameters:

https://realpython.com/prevent-python-sql-injection/