# Using a python dict to create a MySQL insert

Tags: mysql-python

I'm trying to create a MySQL insert from a python dict using the tips found in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9336270/using-a-python-dict-for-a-sql-insert-statement/12492130#12492130).
I'm getting a MySQL error, becouse the syntax is not right. I've tracked down the problem being that in my query, the field names are surrounded by single quotes. My code is:

```
d=dict(a='pepe',b=4,c='potamo')
qmark = ", ".join(['%s'] * len(d))
sql = "INSERT INTO db.table ({}) VALUES ({})".format(qmark,qmark)
c.execute(sql,(d.keys() + d.values())
```

Looking at mysql log, this produces:

```
INSERT INTO db.table ('a', 'b', 'c') VALUES ('pepe', 4, 'potamo')
```

which raises a mysql exception (syntax error).
Using the sentence in the MySQL command line, gives same error, and manually removing the single quotes from the fields fixes it:

```
INSERT INTO db.table (a,b,c) VALUES ('pepe',4,'potamo')
```

So I wonder what is the best way to remove those single quotes, or if there is a way to make `cursor.execute()` (part of Mysqldb) fix it for me.
So far I can only think of something like:

```
str(d.keys()).replace("'","") + str(d.values())
```

and then split the resultant str back to a list to feed it to `cursor.execute()`.
Or create a

```
l=d.keys()
```

and then remove the `'` from each element of the list prior to an

```
execute(sql,(l + d.values())
```

all of wich looks ugly.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
d=dict(a='pepe',b=4,c='potamo')
sql = "INSERT INTO db.table (a, b, c) VALUES (%(a)s,%(b)s,%(c)s)"
c.execute(sql, d)
```