# how can i fix AttributeError: 'dict_values' object has no attribute 'count'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx

here is my [code](http://pastebin.com/tzPpqE97) and the text file is [here](http://www.dropbox.com/s/2bklv7p4ylq8wur/web-graph.zip?dl=0http://)

```
import networkx as nx
import pylab as plt

webg = nx.read_edgelist('web-graph.txt',create_using=nx.DiGraph(),nodetype=int)
in_degrees = webg.in_degree()
in_values = sorted(set(in_degrees.values()))
in_hist = [in_degrees.values().count(x)for x in in_values]
```

I want to plot degree distribution web graph 
how can i change dict to solve?

Comment: I assume you're using Python 3. If that's correct, please add the python-3.x tag to your question. Some of the `dict` methods behave differently in Python 3 vs Python 2.

Answer (score 21):

In Python3 `dict.values()` returns "views" instead of lists:

> - dict methods dict.keys(), dict.items() and dict.values() return "views" instead of lists.
>     https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html

To convert the "view" into a list, simply wrap `in_degrees.values()` in a `list()`:

```
in_hist = [list(in_degrees.values()).count(x) for x in in_values]
```

Answer (score 0):

just use  `list(in_degrees.values()).count(x)`
worked for me!

Answer (score -1):

If you want to count dictionary values you can do it like this:

```
len(list(dict.values()))
```

same method works for keys

```
len(list(dict.keys()))
```

Also keep in mind if you want to get all keys or values in list just use `list(dict.values())`

Comment: `len(mydict)` is sufficient, since in this context the len of a dict is the number of keys. No need to produce a list of the values or keys. And making a copy by the use of the `list` operator is unnecessary as well since both `mydict.keys()` and `mydict.values()` return lists.